# Getting a line number from where a function returned

Tags: c++, debugging, raii

I have a cpp function which has multiple return points based on different flags set and different control flows. Is there a way to figure which return statement was used, without adding a line of debug for each return statement? (it is difficult to figure the return point just from the return value)

I already use RAII to log the entry and exit of the function. And I need the ability to log the line number where it returned.

I tried searching around for this but didnt find anything close to what i want

Comment: You can make use of the `__LINE__` macro, but this would create very brittle code indeed -- can you explain your code a bit more?

Comment: I guess debugging the code, setting a breakpoint where the function starts, and single step through the function is not an option?

Answer (score 3):

Change `return_type fun(args)` to `pair<return_type, unsigned int> fun(args)` and `return val` with `return make_pair<return_type, unsigned int>(val, __LINE__)`

Comment: This is the best non-debug mode option.

Comment: That would mean changing the way it is called everywhere. This is just for debugging purpose and not a general use case. Debug info should be logged in the context, because it's very unlikely a calling functions line number is relevant in caller function. (IMO, passing a default reference argument would be better option, so you don't have to change the existing calls, for eg, `int func(int &lineno = LINE_ZERO`)

Comment: In that case, I would prefer a print statement before return. `PRINT_LINE(); return val;` PRINT_LINE can be defined only for debug mode.

Answer (score 2):

One thing you could do is change the return type of the method to a `Tuple`.

One of the elements in the `Tuple` would be your original return value.

The second element could make use of the `__LINE__` macro.  You could either just return the line number or a `String` including the line number and other possible informative logging information about the return point.

Comment: I agree and the particular type of tuple you're looking for is a 'pair' as described in Mohit Jain's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the standard `__LINE__` predefined macro in your log statement :

From the [gcc documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Standard-Predefined-Macros.html) :

> This macro expands to the current input line number, in the form of a
>   decimal integer constant. While we call it a predefined macro, it's a
>   pretty strange macro, since its “definition” changes with each new
>   line of source code.

Ideally, make your code simpler, reducing the number of return points, or include information about the return point in the returned value itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can use preprocessor macros:

```
#define return std::cerr << __FILE__ << ":" << __LINE__ << " return " << std::endl; return
```

Right before your function definition. And:

```
#undef return
```

So you dont get a lot of log messages with `return`s that you are not concerned about.

Edit:
By the way, if you have a RAII object that you are using to log it the function entry, you may do:

```
#define return entry_raii_object.exited_at(__LINE__); return
```

Dont forget to undef later. I personally would prefer a different keyword for logged returning, like `#define logged_return ...; return`

Comment: Care that it won't work for `if (false) return; /*other code not reached with your macro */` as `return` will not be in *if block* anymore.

Comment: Defining a keyword is illegal, the approach would be fine if the macro was something like 'RETURN' or 'return_' but `return` just does not cut it.

Comment: @Jarod42: Good point on the implementation, but the approach is still sound. The macros can be rewritten as `do { ... } while (false)` to fix that issue

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: Not really as stated. It will need macro `RETURN(val)` and `RETURN_VOID` for that.

Comment: Adding '#define return' for each return statement is more typing than using '#ifndef NDEBUG'.  He doesn't want to add a line of debug code for each statement.

Comment: Obviously, the correct way to do that would be to create a different keyword. I just respected the @theAlias's constraint of not needing to modify every return. Ilegal stuff is valid if you are doing a disposable code just to help debugging something.